# why Bootstrap navbar not collapse in my code

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

here's my bootstrap code so i tried the navbar alone it collapse when minimise it but when i added it with my code i made some changes, but not on the collapsing part so after that it wouldn't collapse at all.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebFit</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse container" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Our blogs
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">recipes</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">muscles</a>
                <!--<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">lifestyle</a>
              </div>-->
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">contact us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Add the complete code for the navbar to your question to help contributors see if / where the problem might be

Answer (score 0):

You have added a 'container' class in the wrong part of your code which has caused the problem

If you remove `container` your navbar will collapse as it should

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse container" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

should be

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion I tried it and it didn't work the navbar still wouldn't collapse. I think there is something else I'm missing in the collapse class.

Comment: Before I answered your question @Yahya I took your code and put it in a Bootstrap4 environment on my own computer _ When I removed the `container` class the navbar collapsed as expected _ You may want to think about clearing your browser cache or trying the code in a different browser _ Give it a try and get back to me if it still doesn't work ; )

Comment: thank you again for the information I did resolve the problem I only added a class to the navbar tag
.
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
.
and it did work honestly I don't fully know why, but I guess what they say in memes is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  the form inside the ul tags .